# Set up reverse dns for anti spam?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I have a VPS LAMP server using Ubuntu with linode.com.  I'm using postfix as the MTA to do mailout.  All my emails, when sent to Yahoo, are flagged as spam.

I want to implement reverse dns to see if it will resolve this issue.   Can someone recommend me a guide for this purpose?

Comment: has this case been solved? I'm on linode as well and having the same problem. All my email is in gmail.hotmail spam, even when reverse DNS and SPF has been set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Linode documentation](http://library.linode.com/linode-manager/configuring-dns-with-the-linode-manager), you can configure reverse DNS records using Linode Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever owns your IP address (your VPS host) will have to setup the reverse DNS for you (they own the IP). Call their tech support - they may provide some tool for this, or they might need to do it manually.

It *is* a public IP that's yours alone, right?